# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND after updating socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, dns, request

I have a service where clients subscribe to a socket connection and listens for updates coming down the pipeline. Once a client has subscribed to a room we send a sendSyncRequest (view below) which calls another service to grab any updated data and it publishes it back down the client through the socket room.

The issue that keeps popping comes when the socket.io version was updated from v1.7.3 to v2.1.1. After deploying the service to a production server everything goes a bit haywire and we start seeing a `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` error that pops up everytime sendSyncRequest gets hit.

Some additional information:

- OS Version: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64)
- Node Version: 4.4.0
- Socket.io Version: 2.2.1
- Request Version: 2.81.0

Error screenshot: 
[getadrrinfo ENOTFOUND error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN7hI.png)

sendSyncRequest Code:

```
function sendSyncRequest(service, accessToken, lastUpdate, socketId, method) {
  var uri = service.scheme + '://' + service.host + ':' + service.port + service.path;

  var options = {
    uri:       uri,
    strictSSL: false,
    timeout:   NO_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT,
    json:      true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }
 };

 if (method === 'get') {
   options.qs = {
     lastUpdate: lastUpdate,
     socketId: socketId
   };
 } else {
   options.body = {
   lastUpdate: lastUpdate,
   socketId: socketId
 };
}

  request[method || 'post'](options, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      log.error('sendSyncRequest', err);
      return;
    }

    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      log.error('sendSyncRequest %d %s', response.statusCode, http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode]);
      return;
    }
  }
);}
```

Socket Server Code:

```
module.exports.init = function (callback) {
log.info('starting new Socket.IO server');
io.origins('*:*');

log.info('initializing socket.io server');

io.attach(server.getServer());

io.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
    log.info('socket.io server disconnect ', socket);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    log.info('new socket.io client %s@%s (%s) connection',
        socket);

    socket.emit('successful_connection', {socketId: socket.id});

    socket.on('disconnecting', function () {
        log.info('socket.io client %s@%s (%s) disconnecting',
            socket.userData.user,
            socket.userData.domain,
            socket.id);

        for (var room in socket.rooms) {
            if (socket.rooms.hasOwnProperty(room)) {
                var count = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room].length;
                log.debug('current room %s connected client count = %d', room, count);

                if (count <= 1) {
                    log.info('unsubscribing from room %s', room);
                    cacheClient.unsubscribe(room);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
};
```

We have also looked into the following github issues which talks about the file descriptor limits, but ultimately this feels like a short term solution.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5545#issuecomment-19007785

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5488

If anyone has any suggestions or fixes, please share, we welcome all the help we can get.